# New Laptop with good specs

Tags: laptop

I have an Asus A52j (K52JK). The laptop has been with me for around 7 years. It is i5. Now I need to get a new one. I am looking for

1. Good CPU (i7 or better)
2. Full Keyboard (with the right keybad)
3. More than 17" display (LED could be better)
4. Good number of USB plugs/connection
5. System RAM - at least 8 GB of memory
6. 2TB SSHD or regular provided that I can upgrade to SSD when their price goes down.
7. Graphics RAM - at lease 4 GB of memory.

Can you please recommend a good one for me?

Comment: Is there an upper limit for the price?

Comment: What kind of software are you running? Any expectations as to battery life or portability? Which country do you need shipping to? Are compact desktops (+ monitor and peripherals) acceptable?

Comment: It should be a laptop. Battery life is not a driving factor. However, good battery life is better. I will be running dual OS: Windows 10 and Ubuntu Linux. Shipping to the US.

Comment: @OOzy Pal, like SEJPM asks, is there a max price limit? Also approximately what kind of work or use?

Comment: Not much of software. Office, Matlab, Dropbox, dual boot.

Comment: TBH you'd be overpaying if I were to recommend a laptop based on your requested specs. You could get away with chroembook like specs if that's all the type software you'd be using.

Comment: It's hard to find a laptop > 17" at a reasonable price. I'd recommend sticking to 17"

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [Laptop Finder feature on LapTopMag.com](https://www.laptopmag.com/laptop-finder). After answering about a half dozen multiple choices questions, it displays a list of up to 10 laptops to consider based on the selection criteria entered while answering the questions.

The requirements of a 17" display and 4 GB of graphics memory will add a significant amount to the laptop cost and limit the selection of applicable laptops.

Based on your stated requirements and some that I inferred ($1K or less target budget and average battery duration), these are the top 5 suggestions generated by the Finder.

1. Lenovo ThinkPad P71 - $1259
2. PowerSpec 1710 - $1400
3. Dell Inspirion 17 7000 2-in-1 (7th Gen Core) - $900
4. Acer Predator Helios 300 (17 inch) - $1357
5. OriginPC Eon 17-X (2018) - $3712

Full disclosure: this website does contain header and right vertical banner advertisements. (I've seen some for Dell & Acer.) That could influence the results generated by the Laptop Finder.

Regarding the processor selection, version 8 is significantly faster and more power efficient than version 7 for the i5 and i7 Intel processors. For many performance tests, an i5 version 8 processor will outperform an i7 version 7 processor. The [Intel 8th Gen vs 7th Gen page on LapTopMag.com](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/kaby-lake-refresh-8th-gen-vs-7th-gen) covers this.

Retailers are just beginning to switch from version 7 to 8. A recent Best Buy website search had about a 2 to 1 ratio of v7 to v8 laptops. So be aware of this difference.

From laptopmag.com on 4/6/2018: [Which Laptop CPU is Right for You?](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/cpu-comparison)

Comment: I would like to mention that the article you linked claiming the i7 8th gen was dramatically better than the 7th gen processors was benchmarking the powersaver (U series) processors. It doesn't seem there is as [dramatic a difference between the "enthusiast" grade i7s (K series)](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-8700K-vs-Intel-Core-i7-7700K/3937vs3647).